Another Old Horror Hammer with Train
This old Hammer Horror I can only remember to the best of my ability the ending.
I saw it in the mid 70's and I am pretty sure it was in colour.
I am unsure if it starred Vincent Price or Peter Lorre or any major actor. And the end may have been set in a dungeon or castle or horror mansion basement.
I think it may have involved a dismembered hand.
The ending was one of these 2: Scenario 1) I think was a guy escaping or escaped onto a train and is standing (maybe) on the caboose platform looking back as the train is pulling away from the camera. And as he is looking back laughing (The camera then pans down ) though he doesn't realise that a hand is attached to the Caboose railing by a chain bumping on the tracks as the train is moving.
Scenerio 2) I think was a guy escaping or escaped onto a train and is standing (maybe) on the caboose platform looking back as the train is pulling away from the camera. And and as he is looking back laughing thinking he escaped but then (The camera then pans down ) he realises to his horror that a hand is attached to the Caboose railing by a chain that the hand had used to follow him.
I apologise for the lack of information and detail but that all I can remember.
